# Как получить список из textEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5, list, список, qtextedit

У меня есть `textEdit`, как получить с него не переменную со всей информацией, а массив. К примеру я ввел в `textEdit`:

```
ВВЕРХ
ВПРАВО
ВЛЕВО
ВНИЗ
СТОП
```

В итоге должен получить массив где каждая строка будет в своей ячейке. Как это сделать?

Comment: О каких ячейках вы говорите? Покажите код, который вы уже написали и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick ячейке в списке. В 0, 1, 2 или другой, как в обычном списке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QString QTextEdit::[**toPlainText**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText)() const
>
> Возвращает текст редактирования текста как обычный текст.

Python String [**split**](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)() Method

Python String [**strip**](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp)() Method

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.btn = QPushButton('Показать список')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.onButton)

        self.label =  QLabel()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)

    def onButton(self):
        lst = [item.strip() for item in self.textEdit.toPlainText().split('\n')]
        self.label.setText(str(lst)) 
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

получаете текст, разбиваете по переводу строки

```
textEdit.plainText.split('\n')
```

Comment: или .splitlines()